# Use enable_if with is_integral to make distribution traits

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I want to make a traits for `std::uniform_*_distribution` according to type given. E.g.:

```
distribution_traits<float>::type int_dist;
```

I tried following ways, but none of them compiles, and I don't know why.

**Implementation 1**

Use `std::enable_if` with `typedef`s:

```
template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits {
  using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type;
  using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>::type;
};
```

Clang 3.4 complains:

```
dist_traits.cpp:7:9: error: redefinition of 'type'
  using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>::type;
        ^
dist_traits.cpp:6:9: note: previous definition is here
  using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type;
        ^
dist_traits.cpp:6:40: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, std::uniform_int_distribution<float> >'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to
      disable this declaration
  using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type;
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dist_traits.cpp:28:3: note: in instantiation of template class 'distribution_traits<float>' requested here
  distribution_traits<float>::type int_dist;
  ^
2 errors generated.
```

**Implementation 2**

Use `enable_if` as class template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename distribution_t = void>
struct distribution_traits;

template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits<
    T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                        std::uniform_int_distribution<T> >::type > {
  using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits<
    T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> >::type > {
  using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>;
};
```

And Clang complains

```
dist_traits.cpp:28:3: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'distribution_traits<float, void>'
  distribution_traits<float>::type int_dist;
  ^
```

Either way cannot be compiled by MSVC++ 12.0, and the error messages are similar.

Could anyone please explain what's wrong I'm doing with SFINAE? Thanks!

---

For those who are curious about solution, here is the one that compiles:

```
template <typename T>
auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type;

template <typename T>
auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>::type;

template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits {
  using type = decltype(dist<T>());
};
```

BTW, if put `dist` function into `distribution_traits`, the compilation will fail with error: function only differs in return type cannot be overloaded. :(

Comment: Use `std::conditional` instead.

Comment: @Rapptz Thanks! With `std::conditional` then it's possible to write `using type = typename std::conditional<b, T, U>::type`. Better code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE can be used to discard overloads of function templates and class template specializations during substitution of template arguments.

It cannot be used with type/template aliases like you're trying to do.

About your working code - putting `dist` inside the class doesn't work because you attempt to call `dist` inside `decltype` without an object. Make `dist` static and it'll work:

```
template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits {
  template <typename U>
  static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<U>>::type;

  template <typename U>
  static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<U>>::type;    

  using type = decltype(dist<T>());
};
```

For implementation 2 to work, you need to omit the second argument of `enable_if`:

template 
struct distribution_traits;

```
template <typename T>
struct distribution_traits<
    T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> {
  using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
};
```

otherwise the specialization you define is `distribution_traits<T, uniform_int_distribution<T>>` and that doesn't match an instantiation like `distribution_traits<float>` because the second parameter is defaulted to `void`.